# If $A$ is infinite set then it is partitionable into denumerable (infinitely countable) sets

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be a non-empty set, such that $\mathbb{N}\preceq A$. Prove that this implies that $A$ is partitionable into denumerable sets.

A hint to this question says that Zorn's lemma is required to prove it. But I'm not very confident when it comes to Zorn's lemma. So I would appreciate your input.

Here's what we are given:

That $\aleph_0 \le |A|$, which means that $A$ is infinite. Also, we are given that there exists an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Let $\{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a partition of $A$. What needs to be shown here is that $P_i$ can be denumerable sets, even if $A$ is uncountable. Now, to apply Zorn's lemma, it is necessary to show that each $P_i$ can be split into chains which have upper bounds. This will lead to the fact that each $P_i$ has a maximal element.

So the questions that I have are the following:

**(1)** If each $P_i$ has a maximal element, how does this indicate that $P_i$ is denumerable? E.g., $(0,1]$ has the maximal element, $1$, but it is not denumerable.

**(2)** What is a good example of a chain contained in $P_i$? My guess is that these can be nested sets. For example, one could create a Cantor-like set contained in $P_i$.

Would appreciate your clarification.

Comment: what is your definition of denumerable? we can easily partition into sets of one element.

Comment: Do you see how the Cartesian product $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ can be split into a collection of denumerable sets?

Comment: @MarkJoshi Denumerable means infinitely countable.

Comment: @bof Yes, but I borrowed from someone else's idea (from a different post): $A_t := \{n+t:n\in \mathbb{N}\}, t\in\mathbb{R}$. Edited my post a bit. Thanks for your question.

Comment: The statements "$P_i$ can be split into chains$" and "$P_i$ has a maximal element" are **meaningless** because no **ordering** has been defined.

Comment: Your questions (1) and (2) are nonsense. Here is a **hint** for the problem in the heading. Use ZL to get a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint denumerable subsets of $A.$ (I.e., if $\mathcal P$ is the set of all collections of pwd denumerable subsets of $A$ ordered by $\subseteq,$ use ZL to show that $(\mathcal P,\subseteq)$ has a maximal element.) Use maximality to show that the maximal collection covers all but finitely many elements of $A.$ Add those elements to one of the denumerable sets in your maximal collection.

Comment: @bof Can you please clarify why a maximal element would cover all but finitely many elements of $A$ instead of covering the entire $A$?

Comment: Covering the entire $A$ is a special case of covering all but a finite number of elements of $A,$ because zero is a finite number. The point is that a maximal element can't leave infinitely many elements of $A$ uncovered.

Comment: @bof But if $M$ is a partition of $A$, how is it possible that some elements, finitely many, are missing from it? Where did they go?

Comment: @bof:  I think your order is a better choice than mine. In essence each step in your chain collects a countably infinite set of elements that were not included before and adds that set to the collection.  Your collections do not account for all the elements at each step, which I was trying to do, but it is not required.

Comment: Can we define $M$ as $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} P_i$? Then it will contain all pairwise disjoint sets. And any collections $Q$ containing $P$ will be contained in $M$. If I'm on the right track...

Comment: The axiom of choice tag is for questions ***about*** the use of the axiom of choice. Not just any question that uses the axiom of choice in the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zorn's Lemma implies that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Let $C$ be the set of all pairwise-disjoint families of countably infinite subsets of $A.$ We have $C\ne \phi$ because $\{B\}\in C$ for some (any) countably infinite $B\subset A.$  We want to find some $c\in C$ with $\cup c=A.$

Consider the relation $\subsetneqq$ on $C$ which for brevity I will call $<.$ Note that $<$ is transitive and irreflexive.

(I).  Suppose $\sigma\in C$ and $\sigma$ is $<$-maximal. That is, $\forall \tau \in C\;(\neg (\sigma < \tau))$.

(Ia). $\sigma \ne \phi$ because $\phi<\{B\}$ for any countably infinite $B\subset A.$

(Ib). $A$ \ $\cup \sigma$ must be finite. Otherwise there exists a countably infinite $B\subset (A$ \ $\cup \sigma)$ but then $\sigma \cup \{B\}\in C$ and $\sigma<\sigma \cup \{B\},$ contradicting the $<$-maximality of $\sigma.$

Now since $\sigma \ne \phi$ and $A$ \ $\cup \sigma$ is finite, we can take some (any) $s\in \sigma$ and let $c=(\sigma \setminus \{s\})\cup \{s\cup (A$ \ $\cup \sigma)\}.$ Then $c\in C$ and $\cup c=A.$

So it suffices to show that $C$ has a $<$-maximal member.

(II). A $<$-chain is a subset $D$ of $C$ such that $\forall d,d'\in D\;( d=d'\lor d<d'\lor d'<d).$  And a $<$-upper bound for any $E\subset C$ (if there is one) is an $x\in C$ such that $\forall e\in E\;(e=x\lor e<x).$

Since $C\ne \phi,$ if we can show that every $<$-chain has a $<$-upper bound, Zorn's Lemma will imply that $C$ does have a $<$-maximal member.

Let $D$ be a $<$-chain. Let $x=\cup D.$

Suppose $c_1,c_2\in x$ with $c_1\ne c_2.$ There exist $d_1,d_2\in D$ with $c_1\in d_1$ and $c_2\in d_2.$ Since $D$ is a $<$-chain we have (by the def'n of $<$) $\;d_1\subset d_2$ or $d_2\subset d_1.$

If $d_1\subset d_2$ then $c_1,c_2$ are unequal members of $d_2$ and $d_2\in C,$ so $c_1,c_2$ are disjoint countably infinite subsets of $A.$

If $d_2\subset d_1$ then $c_1,c_2$ are unequal members of $d_1$ and $d_1\in C ,$ so $c_1,c_2$ are disjoint countably infinite subsets of $A.$

Therefore $x\in C.$ And  $x$ is a $<$-upper bound for $D$ because $\forall d\in D\; (d\subset x),$ which is the same as $\forall d\in D\;(d=x \lor d<x).$................... QED.

Comment: Thank you for your very explanatory answer! I'm actually now beginning to understand how set theory proofs and Zorn's lemma work. I'm very new to this. Can you please clarify why Zorn's lemma implies that any uncountable set contains an infinitely countable subset?

Comment: Let $A$ be infinite. Let $C$ be the set of all $(B,<_B)$ where $B\subset A $ and $<_B$ is a well-order on $B.$  Let $(B,<_B)<^*(B', <_{B'})$ iff $B\subsetneqq  B'$ and $<_{B'}$ restricted to $B$ is $<_B.$...   Any $<^*$-chain has an upper bound, and $C\ne \phi$ so there's a $<^*$-maximal member $(E,<_E) $ and E cannot be finite..... Any infinite well-ordered set  has a countably infinite initial segment..... In fact $E=A$... Zorn's Lemma implies that every set can be well-ordered.

Comment: Does a well-ordered set need to be an at most countable set? Sorry, I don't think I completely got your comment below. If we establish a chain with a well-order, which has a bound, and then by Z.L. we have that there exists a maximal element, how does this show us that every uncountable set has an infinitely countable subset?

Comment: NO a well-order doesn't need to be countable. If $<_B$ is a well-order of $B,$ an initial segment of $B$ is either $B$  or  is $pred (x)=\{y\in B:\; y<_b x\}$  for some $x\in B$....("$pred (x)$" for  "predecessors of $x$ ")... If $B$ is infinite consider the set of $x\in B$ for which $pred(x)$ is finite....Note that  $B$ has  a least member, a 2nd-least member, etc.

Comment: So you say that Z.L. implies that every set can be well-ordered. But why does this mean that every uncountable set contains an at most countable set? I'd think about it this way: why is it impossible to build a chain of uncountable sets?

Comment: It's NOT impossible to build  a chain of uncountable sets, in general.... If $B$ is a well-ordered and infinite, then for each non-negative integer $n$ there is a $unique$ $H(n)\in B$ such that $pred (H(n))$ has exactly $n$ members.  Then $\{H(n): n\in \{0\}\cup \mathbb N\}$ is a countably infinite subset of $B.$

Comment: Can you please let me know?: 1) What if $B$ is not well-ordered, does it  still contain an infinitely countable subset? 2) What can $H(n)$ look like? Say $H(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}$. If I got it right, $H(n)=n\implies pred(H(n)) = n-1$.

Comment: It has been shown that if ZF (the Zermelo-Frankel axiom system of set-theory) (which does not include Zorn's Lemmma) is consistent then ZF cannot prove that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset, .....by using an inner model of a Forcing  extension.It takes a whole book to explain Forcing

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a rather straightforward approach that doesn't need ordering here. We just consider two cases: 1) if $A$ is infinitely countable then we simply break it down into singletons; 2) if $A$ is uncountable, let $B$ be an infinitely countable subset of $A$, then $\{b\},b\in B$ together with $A\setminus B$ is a desired partition.

Comment: It seems like we would need to apply infinite induction, since $A\setminus B$ is uncountable.

Comment: @sequence the only thing we need is an uncountable set admits a proper countable subset.